# Specifying an alternate path for a Haystack template

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

[The Haystack documentation states that](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#handling-data):

> Additionally, we’re providing `use_template=True` on the text field. This allows us to use a data template (rather than error-prone concatenation) to build the document the search engine will index. You’ll need to create a new template inside your template directory called `search/indexes/myapp/note_text.txt`

Unfortunately, there is no information on what to do if you want a differently named template.

Is it possible to specify the path to a haystack document template?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dang it, I was searching for this for a week.

[Its listed under the `SearchField` API documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html?highlight=template_name#template-name), which is the superclass of the actual fields in a search index.

> **`SearchField.template_name`**
>
> Allows you to override the name of the template to use when preparing
>   data. By default, the data templates for fields are located within
>   your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` under a path like
>   `search/indexes/{app_label}/{model_name}_{field_name}.txt`. This
>   option lets you override that path (though still within
>   `TEMPLATE_DIRS`).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> bio = CharField(use_template=True, template_name='myapp/data/bio.txt')
> ```
>
> You can also provide a list of templates, as loader.select_template is
>   used under the hood.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> bio = CharField(use_template=True, template_name=['myapp/data/bio.txt', 'myapp/bio.txt', 'bio.txt'])
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was struggling with this forever. I am surprised they documented this so poorly. Thanks again !